# Integtrating MVC3 and Silverlight Projects

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, silverlight-4.0

I've been working on a project that was run as two separate VS projects. The first a MVC3 project and the second a Silverlight project with dummy MVC project attached. The projects have been working in isolation, but now need to be merged. In the MVC solution I tried adding the SL project expecting it to hook up and ask which website to use, but nothing.

Am I missing a step? Should I merge the physical directories to help the process as well? Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the silverlight project is added to the solution, go in the MVC Project properties, and select the silverlight applications panel. You should be able to add your silverlight application in your website from here.